# Measurement of Traffic Parameters using SNMP

Tags: snmp, management, load-balancer

First, do 'Octets' in [ifInOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifInOctets)  and [ifOutOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16#oidContent) actually refer to packets?  Can someone explain in detail? Also, if I want to measure the traffic flowing between certain set of nodes, how do I achieve it using SNMP? I saw a few links leading to MIB II and RMON. Is there some other way too? Can I measure the traffic delay, number of dropped packets, bandwidth of the network, load balancing parameters and related parameters using SNMP MIBs?

Comment: Octets is a synonymous of "something taken 8 times". In the computer science the "thing" taken 8 times is the bit. Octet=Byte.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First, do 'Octets' in ifInOctets and ifOutOctets actually refer to packets? Can someone explain in detail?

`ifInOctets` and `ifOutOctets` refer to *bytes* received and transmitted (respectively) by the interfaces indexed to [ifIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1) / [ifName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1); `ifInOctets` and `ifOutOctets` use 32 bit wide values.

Unless you're polling interfaces at 100Mbps or lower, I'd strongly recommending using *[ifHCInOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifHCInOctets)* and *[ifHCOutOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifHCOutOctets)*, which are 64-bit values.  The difference is important... for instance a 1GE interface at full TX rate will wrap the 32-bit `ifOutOctets` counters in [34 seconds](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html); that's faster than most people will poll them.

- 32 bit counters @ 10Mbps wrap in 57 minutes
- 32 bit counters @ 100Mbps wrap in 5 minutes, 42 seconds
- 32 bit counters @ 1000Mbps wrap in [34 seconds](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html)

If you want to count packets, use [ifHCInUcastPkts](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.7#oidContent) and [ifHCOutUcastPkts](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifHCOutUcastPkts).  `HC` means they are 64-bits wide... not all SNMP objects need this much space, but high-speed interfaces do.

> Also, if I want to measure the traffic flowing between certain set of nodes, how do I achieve it using SNMP? I saw a few links leading to MIB II and RMON. Is there some other way too? Can I measure the traffic delay, number of dropped packets, bandwidth of the network, load balancing parameters and related parameters using SNMP MIBs?

You can't measure traffic between two servers with SNMP unless there is *nothing* else transmitting to the same servers (i.e. very unlikely).  The best options for measuring between endpoints are:

- [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)
- [netflow](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/index.html) / [sflow](http://www.sflow.org/)
- [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Delay / average packet loss over time is best measured from the hosts with [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) or [winmtr](http://winmtr.net/).  It's pretty hard to measure exact packet loss for individual streams unless you post-process files from [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) with a script (and you'll have to code that by hand).

When you ask about load-balancing parameters, I'm not sure what you mean.

Passive available bandwidth measurement can be done with [yaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209852/667301).  Active measurement isn't a likely use-case given your requests, but use [iperf2](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/), or [iperf3](https://github.com/esnet/iperf) for that.  As of a year ago when I last tried it, [iperf3](https://github.com/esnet/iperf) was still a bit rough around the edges in my experience... I still like [iperf2](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/), but if I don't mention it someone will complain.

Comment: Those SNMP Oids mentioned above worked! And I tried solar winds trial version to find the bandwidth consumption and network top users. Using mrtg, I can plot graphs and do some inference/report genereation. Any idea how I can infer suspicious activities from those graphs/data?

Comment: I'm afraid the definition of suspicious activities is far too localized for me to answer.

Comment: On what basis do network administrators deduce that there might have been an intrusion that took place at a specific interface during a certain interval of time? Say for example, there is a self-replicating worm in the network that causes the traffic at few interfaces to reach the peak! Or some intruder trying to bombard the network with packets (an usual activity) . How can these traces be found out?

Comment: I polled the ifOperStatus and found that few interfaces on a switch were down. And next when I polled the ifHCInUcastPkts/ ifHCOutUcastPkts on the same switch, I found there were packets received or transmitted by those interfaces that were down! How can this be viable?